# Is it ok to use a thumbnail of a stock photo?

Tags: copyright

When browsing the web, there are thumbnails of stock photos.

When they are clicked the artifacts appear and you must pay £60 or whatever to download the photo.  Probably like most people I don't have hundreds of pounds to spend on stock photos at the moment.  Sadly, I spent all my money on chocolate faberge eggs.

If I take the poor quality thumbnail, am I allowed to use it?

Comment: No.It's still copyright infringement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a thumbnail and low quality does not change its copyrights.

You can use it if you change it enough (more than 50%, this is a grey area as to how much the original must be altered before it is considered a new piece).

If you aren't going to sell it or use it on a website or print where you are selling things then you can use it. (if you don't use it for commercial purposes). This means if it's just for your art or private portfolio or non-commercial site then you can use it.

If you buy it or obtain permission from the owners you can use it.

Otherwise you can't use it.

Comment: if i put a filter on the image does that count as a 50% change?  If not what if I remove half the image, is that ok?

Comment: Sorry, i do not know

Comment: That 50% rule is not true. If it recognizable as the original image or part of the original image then the copyright applies.

Comment: Please see I noted the 50% rule as a "grey area". As I remember from the Shephard Fairy case there was debate as to how much a piece must be altered to lose its copyright.